# how to select the difference of second and third highest salary from table without using inner query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Suppose we have one table called `emp` that has only one column called `salary` that has 6 rows only.

I want the result that add the (difference of second highest and third highest salary) and (difference of fourth highest and fifth highest salary).

Note: I don't want to use any inner query for that. so please help me to write this query ?

**Thanks in advance**

```
Please find table below : (this table is not in sorted order)

    |Salary|
    --------
    |150000|
    |130000|
    |140000|
    |160000|
    |180000|
    |190000|
```

I have wrote this following query that given the data but as data is not in sorted order so i am facing the issue

```
ABS(ABS((select salary
        from EMP where rownum <3 minus select salary from EMP
        where rownum <2 )-
    (select salary
        from EMP where rownum <2 minus select salary from EMP
        where rownum <1))-
    ABS((select salary
        from EMP where rownum <5 minus select salary from EMP
        where rownum <4 )-
    (select salary
    from EMP where rownum <4 minus select salary from EMP
    where rownum <3 )))
```

Comment: I guess you could do an order by with top 3, and then make the operations manually

Comment: Is this MySQL or Oracle? Why don't you want to use a subquery?

Comment: Add? Where? In the same column? Add two more columns? (And then what - have the same six rows with Salary column, and the two additional columns showing the same value six times, once in each row?) **OR**... do you mean return a single value (one row, one column) with the sum of the two differences?

Comment: Even if the data was "in order" there is no guarantee that ROWNUM would respect that order. For ROWNUM to work the way you want it to work, you would need a subquery with ORDER BY SALARY DESC at the end, and then only the ROWNUM in the OUTER query could be used this way. So: NO, it is not possible to fix your code.

Comment: ... and I see many subqueries in your code. You said "without subqueries". What gives?

Comment: this is Oracle and i don't want to use any inner query not sub query (its a requirement).

Answer (score 4):

For **Oracle**:

Hard to do without subqueries... unless you are looking for really ugly and inefficient code.

Here is a neat way to do it without subqueries, in Oracle 12.1 and higher, using the `match_recognize` clause:

```
with
     emp ( salary ) as (
       select 150000 from dual union all
       select 130000 from dual union all
       select 140000 from dual union all
       select 160000 from dual union all
       select 180000 from dual union all
       select 190000 from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution!)
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select result
from   emp
match_recognize (
  order by salary desc
  measures (b.salary - c.salary) + (d.salary - e.salary) as result
  one row per match
  pattern ( ^ a b c d e )
  define  a as 0 = 0
)
;

RESULT
------
 30000
```

And here is an elementary (and stupid!) way to do it:

```
select max(e2.salary) - max(e3.salary) + max(e4.salary) - max(e5.salary) as result
from   emp e1 join emp e2 on e1.salary > e2.salary
              join emp e3 on e2.salary > e3.salary
              join emp e4 on e3.salary > e4.salary
              join emp e5 on e4.salary > e5.salary
;
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `NTH_VALUE` Oracle function.

```
SELECT distinct ((NTH_VALUE(salary, 2) OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) - 
                 (NTH_VALUE(salary, 3) OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING))) +
                ((NTH_VALUE(salary, 4) OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) - 
                 (NTH_VALUE(salary, 5) OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)))
FROM emp
```

Comment: `NTH-VALUE` should be `NTH_VALUE`. Other than that, you need a windowing clause so the `NTH_VALUE` is taken over the entire partition; otherwise it's from the top of the partition to the current row (the default), so some of the values will be `NULL`, and then when you select distinct you get `NULL` and the desired answer.